# What happened to PyPI Package Ranking website?

Tags: python, pypi

It has been a few weeks that the PyPI Package Ranking website accessed through http://pypi-ranking.info/ is down and there is no way to access it. Does anybody know what has happened to it?

Comment: Looks like someone probably needs to restart gunicorn or whatever WSGI they are using.

Comment: @C.B. Your answer did not help. Please be more clear and to the point if you have any other suggestions. Perhaps try it out before posting an answer here!

Comment: You may not understand that answer (which is only a comment, anyway, not an answer proper) but it's a reasonable explanation of what might have happened.

Comment: yes. I found the webmaster of the [http://pypi-ranking.info/](http://pypi-ranking.info/) and asked him to take a look at the issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the status of a third-party site.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo : You could have done so when the question was asked. Obviously you did not know the answer then and remained silent !!! Now you know the answer thanks to this thread!!!!
So I am glad you learned something here.

Comment: @Arash_D_B Alternatively, I didn't see it until your answer bumped the question to the front page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out that the website is managed by someone in Japan. I emailed the webmaster and asked him to look into the issue. Now the site is back up again.